# RestController receiving incorrect charset in RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-boot, character-encoding, spring-restcontroller

I have following api:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Search product by text")
@PostMapping("/get/search")
public ResponseEntity<List<ShopProductDTO>> get(@RequestBody SearchProductRequestDTO search) {
    //searching product here using search.getSearchText() value
}
```

Via postman I am sending:

```
{"searchText":"Утюг"}
```

But what I am receiving/seeing in logs:

```
SearchProductRequestDTO{searchText='РЈС‚СРі'}
```

After enabling **DEBUG** I see `Http11InputBuffer` logs where body:

```
{"searchText":"ГђВЈГ‘<U+0082>Г‘<U+008E>ГђВі"}
```

What I have done (none of them helped):

1. Added following properties in `application.properties`

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.messages.basename=messages
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
```

2. Exposed `CharacterEncodingFilter`

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public CharacterEncodingFilter charsetFilter() {
    CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    filter.setForceEncoding(true);
    return filter;
}
```

3. Executed `jar` file with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` param
4. Included following headers in Postman

```
accept-charset:utf-8
content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8
```

What else I should do? Or am I missing something?

Comment: how your log is defined?

Comment: @user7294900 nohup java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar myjar.jar > my.log 2>&1 &

Comment: I mean logger configuration

Comment: @user7294900 we are on early development stage, I did not configured any logging, just writing console output into file. If you are asking how do I enabled debug logging `logging.level.root=DEBUG`

Comment: try adding logging encoding as `logging.console.encoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Search product by text")
@PostMapping(value="/get/search", consumes="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<ShopProductDTO>> get(@RequestBody SearchProductRequestDTO search) {
    //searching product here using search.getSearchText() value
}
```

The change is in your line
 
@PostMapping(**value=**"/get/search", **consumes="application/json;charset=UTF-8"**)

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is **logging**, change logger [encoding](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/logging-application-properties/) to support UTF-8

> ```
> #encoding- Over-ride the default character-encoding scheme.
> logging.console.encoding=UTF-8
> ```